# tkinter Labels and Entrys are misaligned in Mac, working in windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I have created a GUI python program using **tkinter in python 3.6**, The compiled code is working as expected in my windows PC.
However when I tried run the same pyc file in a mac PC with python 3.6 installed, the the text boxes and text labels are misaligned.

[Windows GUI Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4rOL.jpg)

[OSX GUI Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PyPYk.jpg)

===========snippet of code=======

```
root = Tk()
root.title("Cell-Py - Cisco Cellular Output Analyzer")
root.geometry("1450x950")
root.maxsize(width="1450",height="900")


label3 = Label(root, text = 'Extracted Values\n', font=windowFont)
label3.place(x = 650,y = 300)
#
outputTextBox3 = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(root,width=45,height=26,bd=4)
outputTextBox3.place(x = 650,y = 320)

root.mainloop()
```

Question: **Is it the resolution messing it up ? How can I make this compatible with both OSX and Windows?**

Comment: You should probably use `grid` i/o `place`

Comment: This is why you normally shouldn't use `place`, because different resolutions and different fonts will causes changes that you have to account for. `pack` and `grid` will take care of this for you when used with the right options.

Comment: There's no way we can help when you don't give us code that duplicates the problem. Can you create a [mcve] that has just two or three widgets that look right on windows but not on OSX?

Comment: @BryanOakley Thanks for the suggestion, i managed to get it work with "grid"